# 既に実行を開始したプロセスをシェルから切り離すには?

Tags: bash

数時間かかると予想されるスクリプトをbashから起動しました。これを、ログインセッションが切れても一緒に落ちてしまわないように切り離したいです。

```
$ python insanely_long.py
```

たまたまこのマシンにはscreenも入っていないので、これまではnohupでやっていたのですが今回は忘れてしまいました。どうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 38, accepted):

bash/zshでは、disown を利用します。

```
$ perl -e 'sleep 10000'
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 perl -e 'sleep 10000'
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 perl -e 'sleep 10000'
$ bg %1
[1]+ perl -e 'sleep 10000' &
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 perl -e 'sleep 10000' &
$ disown %1
$ jobs
$ exit
exit
```