# virtualenvとPythonを実行しながらPCの電源を切る方法がわかりません。

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, putty

環境はubuntuです。Puttyを経由して操作しています。
virtualenvをactivateして、

```
source bin/activate
```

Pythonを実行して

```
python sample.py
```

と入力しました。
このまま動かしたまま、PCの電源を切りたいんですが、どうすればいいですか？

Comment: 参考: [既に実行を開始したプロセスをシェルから切り離すには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/181/)

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/141838

Answer (score 4):

`nohup`と`&`を組み合わせてコマンドをバックグラウンドで実行してください。

```
$ nohup python sample.py &
```

Comment: [1] 5024　　＃ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
と表示されます。止めるにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: `5024`がプロセスIDなので、`kill`コマンドで強制終了してください(プロセスIDは実行するたび毎回変わります)。 `$ kill -9 5024`

Comment: だめです。-bash: kill: (5024) - No such process
と出ます。

Comment: sample.pyの実行が終了していれば当然プロセスIDも無くなります。バックグラウンドで動いているかは`jobs`コマンド出確認できますが、sample.pyの処理内容が分からないのでこれ以上回答のしようがありません。処理に時間がかかるだけなのか、無限ループ等でユーザーが止めるまで動き続けるはずなのかは、(質問文に書いてくれない限り)あなたしか分かりません。

Answer (score 1):

こういうケースでは、[screen コマンド](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_screen/man1/screen.1.html)を使って仮想端末で操作するのが便利です。

取り敢えず以下のコマンドを知ってれば動かせます。

screen  
仮想端末の作成

Ctrl+a d 
現在の端末から screen をデタッチする。

screen -r 
デタッチされている screen セッションをレジュームする。

また、実行済みの場合は、コメントにあるように`Ctrl+z`で停止させて、`disown`を使用すればいいです。

Comment: わかりました！！ありがとうございます！！